# UITableView on iPad/iPhone like Mail.app

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

how can i made an UITableView looks like the Mail.app from iPhone/iPad? With an heading, the time/date in the right top and 3-5 Lines of text as subtitle?

I cant't find anything about this.

Thank's!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great [tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) about creating your own custom UITableViewCell. Work through that and then you should easily be able to tweak the cell layout to what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this. This tutorial is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to specify the desired UITableViewCell style in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath:" method of your UITableViewController. The available styles can be found in the documentation for UITableViewCell (see the "– initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:" section). Simply type "UITableViewCell" in the search field of the documentation section of Xcode for a complete overview.